# Flutter video_player with URL from Firestore Document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to play a video from a URL of a Firestore Document. To play a video in Flutter, I have to instantiate its Url in the init() method.  I set a default URL to a butterfly video, and the value was supposed to be replaced by the URL obtained from Firestore. (So that it is easy for me to see if the code works). However, the code does not work properly. I got an error that says "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'value' was called on null".

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // Create the initialization Future outside of build
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _initialization,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // Check for error
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print(snapshot.error);
            return Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                  "Something went wrong",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }

          //Once complete, show your application
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return MaterialApp(
              title: 'Flutter Demo',
              home: VideoPlayerScreen(),
            );
          }

          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }
}

class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 
  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String videoUrl =
      'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4';

  @override
  void initState() {
    firestore.collection("videos").get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            // _controller.dispose();
            videoUrl = doc["videoUrl"];
            _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl);
            _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
            print(videoUrl);
          })
        });
    // _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl);
    // _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Flutter Video Player"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
              _controller.pause();
            } else {
              _controller.play();
            }
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firestore.collection("videos").get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            videoUrl = doc["videoUrl"];
            _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl);
            _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
         setState(() {});
            });
         });
     });
  }
```

Since `initialize()` is asynchronous, then you can use the method `then` which will get called when the future completes. Inside the callback, you can call `setState()` which will trigger a rebuild and notify the framework that the internal state of the widgets has changed .

https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

Comment: Thank you. It works now but every time I hot restart the app, the error page shows before the video player is shown.

Comment: What abt when u fully install the app? Try and use `whenComplete` instead of `then`

Comment: It still shows the error before the video player loads up.

Comment: check this https://pub.dev/packages/video_player, I have never used video_player, but they have a property called `initialized` which checks if the controller is initialized or not `child: _controller.value.initialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
              : Container(),` you can use the same way in your code

Comment: I found the problem which is at the child of the floating action button. Since the controller was not initialized at first, _controller.value.isPlaying will throw an error. Thank you so much!

Comment: yes use the `initialized` property to check if it is initialized or not, no problem!